# Database data displaying on html (rails)

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, erb

I am making a rails app that users can use to shop for products. Everything was working fine, then I adjusted the `products#index` page, and now the data from the database is displaying on the html under the `<div>` of the page like so;

```
[#&lt;Product id: 1, name: &quot;Green&quot;, description: &quot;coming from the hills of the emerald triangle, thi...&quot;, strain: &quot;Sativa&quot;, price: #&lt;BigDecimal:7fbe558f8228,&#39;0.2E2&#39;,9(18)&gt;, image_file_name: &quot;http://i.imgur.com/NZkyXpr.jpg&quot;, created_at: &quot;2015-04-12 22:56:42&quot;, updated_at: &quot;2015-04-12 22:56:42&quot;, gram_price: nil, eighth_price: nil, quarter_price: nil, product_type: nil&gt;, #&lt;Product id: 3, name: &quot;Sour Diesel&quot;, description: &quot;Sour, sometimes called Sour D, is an invigo...&quot;, strain: &quot;Hybrid&quot;, price: #&lt;BigDecimal:7fbe55902bd8,&#39;0.2E2&#39;,9(18)&gt;, image_file_name: &quot;http://i.imgur.com/RUHZAXQ.jpg&quot;, created_at: &quot;2015-04-13 01:42:35&quot;, updated_at: &quot;2015-04-13 01:42:35&quot;, gram_price: nil, eighth_price: nil, quarter_price: nil, product_type: nil&gt;, #&lt;Product id: 2, name: &quot;Grand Daddy Purp&quot;, description: &quot;Introduced in 2003 by Ken Estes, Granddaddy Purple...&quot;, strain: &quot;Indica&quot;, price: #&lt;BigDecimal:7fbe559015d0,&#39;0.2E2&#39;,9(18)&gt;, image_file_name: &quot;http://i.imgur.com/8O5kXeL.jpg&quot;, created_at: &quot;2015-04-13 01:41:17&quot;, updated_at: &quot;2015-04-13 07:31:14&quot;, gram_price: nil, eighth_price: nil, quarter_price: nil, product_type: nil&gt;]
```

Here is my index page, along with my controller

**index.html.erb**

```
<section class="product-page">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row text-center">
      <%= @products.each do |product| %>
        <div class="product col-md-4 text-center">
          <h2><%= link_to product.name, product_path(product.id) %></h2>
          <%= link_to image_tag(product.image_file_name),
              product_path(product.id), :class => 'img-responsive' %>
           <div class="product-info">
             <div class="product-info-left"><%= product.descrip %></div>
             <div class="product-info-right"><%= product.price %></div>
           </div>   
        </div>
        <% end %>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

**products_controller.rb**

```
class ProductsController < ApplicationController


  def index
    @products = Product.all
  end

  def show
    @product = Product.find(params[:id])
  end


end
```

Does anyone know why the data from the database would be displaying on my html page? Did I forget to close a tag, is there something in my controller? I can also attach an image that shows what it looks like if my description isn't clear. Any tips would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<%= @products.each do |product| %>
```

must be

```
<% @products.each do |product| %>
```